Accessing elements from empty typed array does NOT return undefined in Typescript. undefined in runtime
Typescript does NOT show errors or warnings when accessing undefined property in VSCode:

BUT I get lastMessage is undefined in runtime.
What can i do to catch undefined value before runtime?
I tried explicitly setting the type of lastMessage to Message | undefined but I still get const lastMessage: Message from Typescript
export type Chat = {
  id: string;
  members: ChatUser[];
  name?: string;
  messages?: Message[] | undefined;
  order?: string;
  _count: { messages: number };
};

const newChat: Chat = {
  id: "1",
  members: [{ id: "1", login: "test", isOnline: true }],
  _count: { messages: 0 },
};

const lastMessage = newChat.messages[0];

const isRead = lastMessage.isRead;


I can't reproduce. Please edit the code to be a [mre] including any relevant compiler options (my suspicion is that if you enable --strict the problem will go away). And please define ChatUser and Message for us... or even better, replace them with built-in types.

Are you looking for noUncheckedIndexedAccess? See How to handle potential empty array when accessing by index in Typescript and Demo of your code with the option enabled.

I've made some extensive explanation inside the snippet
You've made some typescript errors, since "newChat.messages" can be undefined, you cannot cast a deconstruction of the object.
Some other techniques are written bellow as optional chaining and ternary operations.
It's a pretty common error for beginners, I hope the snippet is clean and readable for you!


console.log("Your code bellow and why it doesnt work:")
// Your Code Explained:

// Use interface for Object types
//
//   export interface Chat {
//     id: string;
//     members: ChatUser[];
//     name?: string;
//     messages?: Message[] | undefined;
//     order?: string;
//     _count: { messages: number };
//   };

// Type removed due to Stackoverflow snippet limitations
{
    const newChat = {
        id: "1",
        members: [{ id: "1", login: "test", isOnline: true }],
        _count: { messages: 0 },
    };

    // .messages does not exist on object newChat
    console.log("newChat object print:", newChat);

    try {
        const lastMessage = newChat.messages[0];
        const isRead = lastMessage.isRead;

        console.log("This won't be printed");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("This will be printed due to error on Try block");
    }
}


// Correct code:
console.log(" ")
console.log(" ")
console.log("Correct code bellow:")
{
    // Avoid use the word "new" for non-class objects
    const chat = {
        id: "1",
        members: [{ id: "1", login: "test", isOnline: true }],
        messages: [],
        _count: { messages: 0 },
    };

    // .messages exists now, but is an empty array
    const lastMessage = chat?.messages?.[0];
    console.log("lastMessage is =>", lastMessage);

    // isRead is undefined
    const isRead = lastMessage?.isRead;
    console.log("isRead is =>", isRead);
}

// You can also add a ternary operation to avoid crashing the code in case of null or undefined 'messages'
console.log(" ")
console.log(" ")
console.log("Alternative code bellow:")
{
    const alternativeChat = {
        id: "1",
        members: [{ id: "1", login: "test", isOnline: true }],
        messages: [],
        _count: { messages: 0 },
    };

    const alternativeLastMessage = alternativeChat?.messages?.[0] ?? [];
    const isRead = alternativeLastMessage?.isRead;

    console.log("Nothing crashed here!");
}




I don't see how this answers "What can i do to catch undefined value before runtime?" given that it offers runtime solutions.

Also, I don't get why add the misleading comments "Avoid use the word "new" for non-class objects" why though? It's a perfectly valid as part of an identifier name. Not to mention it doesn't matter whether something was a class or not - a very common pattern is to have a change listener for a value that fires with two parameters, the old value and the new value. Commonly named oldValue and newValue. And the values are rarely objects, I'm talking about change listeners for primitives.

"You can also add a ternary operation to avoid crashing the code in case of null or undefined 'messages'" there are exactly zero ternary operators used in your code. There is the nullish coalescing ?? which is a binary operator - operates on two values a ?? b - if a is nullish, it returns b. The nullish safe property access ?. is similarly not ternary. Ternary operator means it operates on three values. Like the conditional operator a ? b : c
